# All windows minimized every 12.3 seconds then a mouse click emitted

Tags: windows-7, windows, mouse, windows-registry, logging

Yep, it's pretty specific, I know..

**I have a user that has this issue:**

While using his laptop (*ThinkPad T420*) and having any number of windows opened, something will close them **every 12.3 seconds** (*Yes I used stopwatch :)* ) and then a **single left mouse click is emitted**.

I prepared a setup and took a video that demonstrates is pretty well I hope, [please see the video for yourself](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3812442/room-15/12_Second_minimize_and_click.mp4) or check out the gif animation below:

---

[image: Gif Animation]

It is recorded of a remote connection, since I don't have physical access to the machine.
You can see the single click right after the windows (*including the Task Manager*) are minimized, it is reopened right away automatically thanks to the click being emittet (*while the cursor is above it's icon in the bottom bar*).

Curiously this doesn't happen when I am logged in as **local adminstrator**, but when I created a brand new user account the issue presented itself again!

I just can't find what is doing this.. so to the actual question:

### 1) Is there a way to find out what/how is it minimizing the windows?

I checked the PC with MSSEC, which found and removed one infection and then also with ASET NODE 32 which found nothing anymore. I checked the registry with [Autoruns for Windows](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) which found:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\Run
```

with
    Name: 3673029395    Type: REG_SZ    Data: C\PROGRA~3\msodud.exe
[This is what VirsuTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/53df45d1efae3e327602c31d5da315f926a701b2c899e6c04382003e208c9fad/analysis/) has to say about that file.

### Anyways so I removed the file but something stayed behind and won't let me remove that registry entry. As seen below:

[image: Registry fun]
Alternatively [here's a link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3812442/room-15/registry.mp4) to the video.

**Those two issues might not be connected but they also might!**

So the question two is:

### 2) Is there a way to find out which application is listening to changes on a certain registry record?

Thanks for reading this wall of text with 50MBs of GIFs, I really have no ideas how to deal with this anymore..

Comment: Since you know that there was at least one infection, you might try yet another AV, such as Kaspersky or Malwarebytes, perhaps running from bootable media. In addition, you might use Task Manager or Sysinternal's *Process Explorer*, *run as* Administrator while in the problematic accounts, sort processes by *CPU*, and look for an unknown process. For the Registry, you may need to change permissions on a Key. Also check *Task Manager* for strange tasks.

Comment: Permissions on a key, that's a good idea. I didn't know that was possible, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

Comment: Have you thought about separating this post of yours into two independent questions? I think both of them are quite interesting, but your monolithic one is not so much because most of the backstory is completely unrelated to the questions themselves.